# Update records in table with CTE in join

Tags: join, sql-update, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression

I've been looking at this update statement that includes a join to a cte for a while.  Not able to figure out the problem.  It's giving me: "Syntax error: unexpected 'UPDATE'. (line 7)".  Not sure what I'm missing.  Thanks!

```
WITH SALESORDER_CTE AS 
(
    SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(ORDERITEMDRUGMODIFIED, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS PM') AS CUSTBODY_ORDERITEMDRUGMODIFIED, *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TRANID ORDER BY ORDERITEMDRUGMODIFIED DESC) AS RN
    FROM SALESORDER
)
UPDATE a
SET a.ORDERITEMDRUGMODIFIED = b.ORDERITEMDRUGMODIFIED
FROM SALESORDERLINE AS a
INNER JOIN SALESORDER_CTE AS b ON a.TRANSACTION = b.ID
WHERE b.RN = 1
AND b.ID = 5369076;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two syntax problems here.  First, the join condition is implicit and should appear in the `WHERE` clause, as `ON` is not supported.  Second, the left hand side of the `SET` clause should not have an alias.  Try this version:

```sql
UPDATE a
SET ORDERITEMDRUGMODIFIED = b.ORDERITEMDRUGMODIFIED
FROM SALESORDERLINE AS a
INNER JOIN SALESORDER_CTE AS b
WHERE a.TRANSACTION = b.ID AND
      b.RN = 1 AND
      b.ID = 5369076;
```